# Place Button next to input text

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, flask, button

How can I place buttons next to input texts like [in this photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FKUO4.png)?

I've this code:

```
<form action='/posts/comment/{{id}}' method='POST'>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name='comment' id='comment' placeholder="Comment as {{name}}..." aria-label="Comment as {{name}}...">
</form>
```

Comment: what is issue you are facing ? give your full code which you trying. Your screenshot outline not clear due to highlight what you exactly need

Answer (score 0):

Answering based on question and screenshot.

```css
button{
margin-left:-6px;
border-left:none;
}
```

```html
<form action='/posts/comment/{{id}}' method='POST'>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name='comment' id='comment' placeholder="Comment as {{name}}..." aria-label="Comment as {{name}}...">
    <button>Save Comment </button>
</form>
```